# is this the correct way to interact with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, architecture, entity-framework-4

I am Working on Entity framework to get started with it. Below is the way i have arranged my projects to interact with EF. I just want to know if i am heading to the right direction or not. Please do suggest the better approach. Please ignore the architecture things like UI should not have reference to DAL. This is just "get to know" project. :)

This is what i am doing:

One project for DAL. Here all the DB operations will be doing using EF.

Model - Business Entity classes. Instead of returning Order object of EF, i will be returning Entity Class of Model. (Is there a way to map my Business Entities to EF entity?)

UI - This will call DAL and get things done.

Project 1 - DAL

This project also contains my edmx file.

```
public class DALRepository
{

    OrderEntities orderEntitiesContext = new OrderEntities();

    public IQueryable<Model.OrderModel> GetOrders ()
    {
        return orderEntitiesContext.Orders.Select(o => new Model.OrderModel { OrderName = o.OrderName, Id = o.OrderID });
    }
}
```

Project 2 - Model

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
}
```

Project 3 - UI

```
public partial class OrderList : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DAL.DALRepository dal = new DAL.DALRepository();
        GridView1.DataSource = dal.GetOrders();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider adding an interfaces project with the API needed outside the DAL to enable unit testing without the DAL and a implementation project that implements those interfaces using the DAL project.

Comment: Correct. Like is said this is just "get to know EF" project. I know how much pain it can bring if i want to unit test it and doesnt expose interface. :)

Comment: one small question. Is this what they call Entity Framework with POCO objects?

Comment: It can be, depends how you generate your entities. (If they inherit from an EF base class or not.)

Comment: No. My Model clasess dont inherit from EF class. They are just plain models.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is excellent and you are in the right path.

I would also suggest to use Architecture Project in the VS Solution to restrict other developers from cross calling against incorrect projects and keeping the proper SoC.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you are on the right path. 
It is sometimes cumbersome to create projections, you will forget a property sooner or later.

This is a framework to copy properties from a source object to a target object:
http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

> one small question. Is this what they call Entity Framework with POCO objects?

From what you have shown this would be referred to as [CodeFirst](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx)

Comment: i guess CodeFirst is better. gives me better control on what i am doing.